# Private key raw format

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, private-key-import, recover-private-key, private-key-export, raw

Hello everyone I'm new here and i have a question, i've send btc to my wallet on an app (lunu) and it didn't arrive so this is the message they send me:

> Dear Customer,
>
> The problem is that you have used a decommissioned app, as you
> mentioned in the beginning of our conversation.
>
> We never got the amount you have transferred.
>
> We would like to advise you to export the raw key with your Lunu
> wallet konfigurations to get a possibility to forward your amount back
> to your personal wallet.
>
> Kind regards

And they also told me to import my private key in raw format but that's not working anywhere maybe someone can help me out